# Get the domain name in Twig/Timber to output in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, twig, wordpress-theming, timber

When I have an error in my custom WordPress theme I would like to output the webmaster email address which would be webmaster@mydomainname.com but I am a bit baffled on how to do this in Twig/Timber in the most straightforward way: `<p class="text-danger fw-bold">PAGE ERROR - Please contact Webmaster at webmaster@{{ #notsure# }}</p>`

`webmaster@{{ site.url }}` just outputs: **webmaster@https://mywordpress.local** which obviously won't work.

UPDATED: To get by I am using `webmaster@{{ site.url[8 :] }}` as that strips away the https:// and outputs **webmaster@mywordpress.local** but seems there should be a cleaner way somehow?

Comment: You can get domain name in PHP with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and pass it to twig but I would recommend to create option for webmaster email and pass it not domain. Your decision is not good enough as site may not have SSL (start with `http://` so the first letter of your domain will be deleted)

Comment: That is a good thought, I think I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. You can use Advanced custom field. Make a email field and then print that value inside the twig file. Inside advanced custom field, you can add any email you have no need to extract a domain name. For more information follow this reference: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/

2. Second method is the way you doing is correct but you need to split domain name from site.url using slice method:

```
{% set website = "https://mywordpress.local" %} //
//calcualting length of string
{% set lengthOfWebsite = website|length %} 
//using length here to split the string accordingly. 8is for split "https://" from actual domain name.
{% set domainName = website|slice(8,lengthOfWebsite) %} 
webmaster@{{domainName}}
```

For the first line of code in your case will be:

```
{% set website = site.url %}
```

For the last line

```
webmaster@{{domainName}}
```

can also be replaced by:

```
{% set actualDomainName = 'webmaster@' ~ domainName %}
{{actualDomainName}}
```